How can i retrieve how much an Azure Function app is being used?
I have about 100 function apps in Azure and I want to get some data about the apps.
In specific what i want to be able to check is how much these apps are being used by customers.
I have tried using the following in Powershell
  az monitor app-insights metrics show --resource $APP_SERVICE_NAME --metric "Requests" --   aggregation "Count"

I am not sure if this metric is correct.
Which metric do i need to check to see how often a function app is being used or accessed by clients ?

You are in right direction, you check it using that Azure cli  command or directly you can open in Azure Portal In monitoring section of Function app to check the logs:

As you have said you have multiple function app to get details of each function app you can use Azure Cli command:
az monitor app-insights metrics show --resource-group "rithwik" --app "rithw12" --metric "Requests" --aggregation "Count"


Now application insights for these apps is not enabled , would that matter ?

running this command doesnt seem to return in powershell , it just sits there ?

In the azure portal what do i look for in the requests ? Also when i click on log it doesnt show a list as you see . I dont think it is enabled ?

If application insights then it will be hard to figure out if it is been used or not.

Ok fair enough ... can i get how much the resource is costing ?

Check this

Ok i have installed app insights on my app. It seems that someone is pushing through thousands of api calls . Can i get the user doing it , maybe by ip or name or something  ?

But what i found is when i enable app insights the service crashes , have you experienced that ?

No i have not experienced that

Is there a setting i need to put in Environment variables ?

Ok , so can i get the details of the user pushing through thousands of api requests to the app ? Would it be under requests ? How can i get it ?

@Jenny If your initial question was answered please accept it. Please raise a new question if needed. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions

The  answer doesnt really address my issue . It may have been answered but its not of any benefit
